# Eclipse GEF - Not able to use classes from javafx control

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-gef

I am developing an application that makes use of Eclipse GEF 5 (Version 5.0.5 to be more precise).

Now I want to do something very equal to the mvc logo example. The part I am concentrating on  at the moment is the palette.

I am not comfortable with the palette hiding and only be visible at mouse cursor above a small line and therefore changed this to be visible on the left side all the time.

In fact, what was available with GEF 3 (GraphicalEditorWithPalette) was almost perfect for my use case.

Therefore I tried to add to PaletteRootPart a JavaFX Accordion.
Working with VBoxes etc (comming from javafx.graphics.jar works smooth) but not with Accordion (coming from javafx.controls.jar).
If I add the Accordion during compile time there is no compile error - the Accordion is therefore resolveable (at least in P2 build.).
The problem is that at runtime, as soon as the editor starts an

`org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.Accordion
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:396)
```

Exception is thrown. Full stack trace at the end of this question.

Before adding the Accordion it worked fine. Therefore I assume that my general setup is at least not really bad :-)

I was curious whether the GEF logo example behaves the same as my application.
And this is the case.
Setting up the GEF dev environment (according to [GEF Wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/gef/blob/f2384c5632f68b0ca2dec4088ffa2118214a8909/CONTRIBUTING.md)) and starting the GEF MVC Logo Example worked finde. But as soon as I inserted

```
Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
```

in the `PaletteRootPart` `createContentLayer()` method it complains with the same exception at runtime.

To be honest I really don't know where to start to debug or solve this. Therefore if additional information is needed please don't hesitate to ask.

My questions are:

1. Is there a possibility to do what I try to do or is that a useless approach? If so how could the mentioned exception be possibly solved?
2. Would it be a possibility to implement the palette in SWT code and link it somehow to the JavaFX part of the editor?

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Full stack trace of exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2024-01-10 13:03:34.710
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' from bundle '399'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.Accordion
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1080)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.Accordion
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.examples.logo.parts.PaletteRootPart.createContentLayer(PaletteRootPart.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.LayeredRootPart.doCreateVisual(LayeredRootPart.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.LayeredRootPart.doCreateVisual(LayeredRootPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.AbstractVisualPart.getVisual(AbstractVisualPart.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.AbstractVisualPart.unregister(AbstractVisualPart.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.AbstractVisualPart.setAdaptable(AbstractVisualPart.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.parts.AbstractVisualPart.setAdaptable(AbstractVisualPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gef.common.adapt.AdaptableSupport.dispose(AdaptableSupport.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.viewer.InfiniteCanvasViewer.dispose(InfiniteCanvasViewer.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.gef.common.adapt.AdaptableSupport.dispose(AdaptableSupport.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.domain.HistoricizingDomain.dispose(HistoricizingDomain.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.fx.ui.parts.AbstractFXView.dispose(AbstractFXView.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.gef.mvc.examples.logo.ui.view.MvcLogoExampleView.dispose(MvcLogoExampleView.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:365)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:385)
    ... 90 more
```

Comment: Is this a RCP application (Eclipse based application)? In which way did you add the dependency containing `javafx.scene.control.Accordion`? Please show your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: Yes it  is a RCP application. 
The GEF examples are meant to run in an eclipse IDE context.

The Manifest.MF is, in case of JavaFX and as far as I understood the documentation (one one the many explanations to be found here https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2020/01/28/setting-up-efxclipse-rcp-development-for-java11-and-pde/ or in the e(fx)clipse documentation), of no use here. e(fx)clipse will add the JavaFX dependencies as plugin dependencies. There exists no OSGi compatibel set of plugins of JavaFX (as far as I know - therefore e(fx)clipse was developed to do the dependency binding.

Comment: So the JavaFX jars are part of my build path (compilation works!). Only at runtime this exception is thrown. I assume this has something to do with GEF is handling the dependencies to JavaFX in comparison but I am not sure - its just an assumption...

Comment: I also tried to go with the org.reficio p2-maven-plugin to get eclipse plugins from the openjfx plugins one can find in the maven central. But this leads to even more weird exceptions at runtime and the p2 build in the eclipse was throwing compile errors then. Because the e(fx)clipse provides then the same classes in the same packages as the openjfx "plugins" which gets the classloader into class loading exceptions.

Comment: Please show the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of your(!) plugin. Are you aware that in OSGi bundles/plugins can be started and stopped at runtime and that dependencies therefore have to be specified in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

Answer (score 2):

I found out at least the reason why GEF is behaving as it is:
Accordion needs a setup JavaFX Toolkit, which is not the case at the point in time where the PaletteRootPart is created.The JafaFX Toolkit initialization happens to be executed to a later point in time in MvcFxUiModule.

The thrown exception about not initialized Toolkit is unfortunately masked by the behaviour of org.eclipse.gef.common.adapt.inject.AdapterInjector. The thrown Exception is catched and transformed into an inner object. The information is then lost to the user.

Took me a good amount of time to debug and get to this point.

A solution is something that needs further investigations about the behaviour of GEF.
If I trigger a startup of the JavaFX Toolkit in the palette root part then the  FXCanvas instantiation in MvcFxUiModule will throw an Exception that the toolkit is already initialized. I will update as soon as I found a solution/workaround.

Comment: Information on [JavaFX platform startup is in the JavaFX JavaDoc,](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) in case that might assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That indeed is helpful.
The main problem, nevertheless, is how Eclipse GEF is organizing itself. 
What I did now is to not instantiate an Accordion or any UI content within the createContentLayer Method of PaletteRootPart (because this method is called as a result of the dependency injection mechanism). Instead I wait now for the FXCanvas to be instantiated and afterwards create the palette content.